# Tag name clash: SIP is a VoIP protocol and a Python native library binding tool

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm answering questions on SO tagged [sip](/questions/tagged/sip), as in Session Initiation Protocol. I just saw a question tagged SIP as in the name of a python native library binding tool.

It's completely tolerable, I'm just interested in what should be done in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup, I'm new on meta :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[sip](/questions/tagged/sip) has already a wiki page that makes clear for what the tag should be used.

> The Session Initiation Protocol, defined in RFC 3261, is an application layer signalling protocol for establishing and modifying long-running relationships between two or more peers.

If there are enough questions about the Python tool, then such questions should be tagged [python-sip](/questions/tagged/python-sip), or with a similar tag, and a wiki should be added to the tag to be sure it is not understood to be used for the Python implementation of the SIP protocol.

Comment: Thanks, sounds reasonable to me! I'll check back later and accept if no counterarguments are raised.